# Java - Invoking a method causes IllegalAccessError

Tags: java

I have a simple function for loading the class "Myclass" from the selected directory.

```
    // Variables
    File temp = new File("some path...");
    String class_name = "MyClass";

    // Directory url
    URL[] urls = null;
    try {
        urls = new URL[]{temp.toURI().toURL()};
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Loading the class
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    Class clazz = null;
    Object clazz_instance = null;
    try {
        // Loads class
        clazz = cl.loadClass(class_name);
        // Creates instance
        clazz_instance = clazz.newInstance();

        // Invoking method "myMethod"
        try {
            Method m = clazz.getMethod("myMethod");
            m.invoke(clazz_instance);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Let us assume I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        MyOtherClass moc = new MyOtherClass();
        // ...... some code
    }
}

class MyOtherClass {}
```

But when I want to call the method "myMethod" I get the:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class "MyOtherClass" from class "MyClass"
```

I am asuming that the problems comes from the fact that the "MyOtherClass" is not public (It can not be, since it is in the same file than "MyClass").

How can I fix this ?

Comment: The code compiles though? And does directly calling the method work? `MyClass.class.getMethod( "myMethod" ).invoke( new MyClass() );` works for me so there must be some difference (e.g. in the classloaders involved etc.).

Comment: Yes, the code compiles with no problems.

Comment: If it's acceptable, you could try making ```MyOtherClass``` a nested class of ```MyClass```

Comment: From the JavaDoc on `IllegalAccessError`: "Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed." - Did you change the class somehow? Did you try with a complete recompile?

Comment: It works if I create MyOtherClass as a nested class of MyClass lie Jorn Vernee has said. However I would like to know if this can be done without nesting - Since I do not know what kinda files (with nested classes or not) will I be getting?

Comment: I think the answer just posted was correct. Making ```MyOtherClass```nested just makes sure it is loaded when ```MyClass``` is.

Comment: The problem might actually be the classloader, i.e. `cl` loads `MyClass` but `MyOtherClass` is probably loaded by a different classloader hence the access error. Try with `new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader())` or use `MyOtherClass.class` instead of `this.getClass()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not loading the dependency class first from the code. Put your MyOtherClass in its own file and set it as public. Then Load it as below.

```
 cl.loadClass("MyOtherClass");
 cl.loadClass(class_name);
```

If you stick to have both the classes in the same file. Define it as below

```
public class MyClass {
    class MyOtherClass {}
    public void myMethod() {
        MyOtherClass moc = new MyOtherClass();

    }
}
```

Comment: OK, will use the nesting classes. Other solutions do not work for me, as I need it work for multiple (potentially unknown classes).